# what is the does the preference tag for di.xml do

Tags: magento2

I was wondering what is the purpose preference tag and the use for the tag in magento?

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface" type="Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\Writer" />
```

Answer (score 2):

`Object Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\Writer` will rewrite object `Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface`.

You can read the following link to more understand:
http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_preferences/